# Basic chain rule question

Tags: calculus

Using the chain rule I am led to believe that the following can be differentiated nicely using the chain rule:

$f(x)=\dfrac{1}{(1+e^{-x})}$

It has been 3 years since I have used calculus though.  If someone could show me how it's done and what $u$ and $v$ are then I would really appreciate it.

Thanks very much.

Comment: there is no $x$ in your expression. I assumed your $z$ is meant to be an $x$ in my solution.

Comment: Sorry guys, f(x) was meant to be f(z) so I want to differentiate wrt z.. not x!  Sorry for confusion

Comment: If you write $\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}} = (1+e^{-x})^{-1} = u^{-1}$ then you can apply the chain rule.

Comment: No it's not complex, it's real.  Changing to x not to stop that confusion... Thanks.

Comment: guy Yes, I realised it must have been real after I wrote that comment and deleted it afterwards.  I hope the answer I gave below helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

guy.  You can calculate the derivative as follows:

Let $u = 1+e^{-x}$.  Note that $u'(x) = -e^{-x}$.  Then $f(x) = 1/u(x)$ and
$$
f'(x)
 = -\frac{1}{u^2(x)}\cdot u'(x)
 = -\frac{1}{(1+e^{-x})^2}\cdot(-e^{−x})
 = \frac{e^{−x}}{(1+e^{-x})^2}.
$$
Note that
$$
f'(x)
 = \frac{e^{−x}}{(1+e^{-x})^2}
 = f(x)\frac{e^{−x}}{(1+e^{-x})}
 = f(x)\frac{1+e^{−x}-1}{(1+e^{-x})}
 = f(x)\Big(1-\frac{1}{(1+e^{-x})}\Big),
$$
so
$$
f'(x) = f(x)(1-f(x)).
$$
I hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Glen, I remember doing something like that in the past, thanks.  However, the answer I was hoping someone would get is $f(x)(1-f(x))$ because I have been working on something an it says that $f(x)$ differentiates nicely to $f(x)(1-f(x))$.  Any ideas how?  I can't see it yet :S.

Comment: By the way.. LaTeX in this comment isn't viewing properly with Chrome (is with Firefox) so hopefully you can read it.

Comment: @computing-guy sure, it is a rearrangement.  I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @Glen.. fantastic.  Thank you so much.  Sorry if it was a trivial question.  I've been in computing for a few years now so I'm a but rusty with some of the mathematics!

Comment: @vivid-colours Absolutely no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u(z)=1+e^{-z}$. Then, $f(u)=1/u$

Comment: Hey picakhu, I made a mistake in my post.  Please see edit.